# How to renew my Apple Developer Program Account after it has expired?

Tags: apple-id, development, developer-program

I'm having trouble renewing my Developer Program Account which expired a month ago.

I have emailed Apple about this issue a few times but their help was, at best, unclear.

I log into the Member Center, click on the Your Account tab, and under Account Summary (on the left) I have 3 sections: Apple ID Summary, Contact Preferences, and Memberships.

The Memberships section tells me (currently) that my Developer Program Status Enrollment was Withdrawn, with a button to "Join Today".

Previously this section told me that my Developer Program Status had expired, and the button invited me to rejoin. I clicked on the button and went through the process, filling in all the same information that I had previously put in over a year ago. I eventually arrived at the part where my application was under review.

A day later I get an email saying I cannot enroll in the Developer Program because there is already a Developer Program Account out there with my details. I responded back telling them that I am simply trying to renew my Developer Program (not start a whole new Account), and they tell me that I can renew my Developer Program in the Member Center.

Now I've gone through the Member Center again and again and for the life of me, I cannot see anything that relates to renewing my Developer Program other than the section that tells me my enrollment has been withdrawn.

Can anybody help? All I want to do is renew my account.

Answer (score 2):

I have run into a similar issue like this before when I was taking my ACMT certification. Essentially I created an iCloud email account and tried to use it to take my 10.9 Apple Certified Associate certifications fine but when I went to take my ACMT and log into GCX it told me I could not with that Apple ID.

After calling Apple and being on the phone with a few different people for a few hours they came to the conclusion that I needed to create a new Apple ID in order to take my ACMT. Luckily I was able to transfer my certifications over to my new Tech ID just fine.

Sometimes an Apple ID can get messed up in there system and there is nothing Apple can do about it. I would create a new Apple ID and renew your developer account with it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your developer account, but in an incognito mode browser and the renew membership banner will appear to allow you to renew.

I had the same issue and that's what fixed it for me.